# Do any online services offer printable maps with my itinerary drawn on?

Tags: online-resources, maps, itineraries, souvenirs

I'm preparing a present for a friend, which is a collection of photos and items from a couple of of travels we've done together.

An idea I had was to somehow display our itinerary with notes and perhaps some pictures for each trip, like it is done here this one (although I would prefer it if the lines followed roads):

[image]

I've tried my maps by google maps and have found it useful but not perhaps as customisable (e.g. change line size and colour) and pretty as I would have hoped. Are there any other similar online services that I can use? I would want to print it out myself rather than order it by mail.

Note: I'm not sure if this is on topic, reading the rules didn't clarify it for me. I'd of course be happy to migrate it to another SE

Comment: I think it fits here, but if it doesn't you may be interested in the [rebooted Website Recommendations proposal on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92540/website-recommendations).

Comment: I've probably seen 20+ of those maps done on Google Maps and none visibly from any other service; if there is another option, it's probably not nearly as well-known

Answer (score 2):

Although not technically an online tool, [ITN Converter](http://www.benichou-software.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=4&Itemid=3&lang=en) allows you create precise itineraries following roads traced on top of maps from Google Maps. With ITN converter you can create journeys and way-points to be uploaded in satellite navigation systems, as well as exportable Google Maps journeys. You can do all of this via the Editor feature:

[image: ITN Converter]

I don't remember if you can customise line colours and such, and can't test this feature since the Editor crashes when run from Wine on Linux. Try it out and let us know.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an itinerary in GPX format (with routes and route points) you can create a printable PDF map on [Inkatlas](https://inkatlas.com). Smaller maps (6 pages or fewer) are free.

Full disclosure: this is my project.